# Why did my combined reputation suddenly spring from 24k to 27k?

Tags: bug, reputation, combined-flair

My combined reputation (as shown on my [combined flair](https://stackexchange.com/users/1988549/peterh?tab=accounts)) yesterday was yet 24k, now it is 27k.

Well, today was a quite fruitful day for me, I've hit the repcap on the Unix SE! But it is only 200 rep, and not 3k.

Unfortunately I can't show a proof from my flair yesterday, because I didn't save it, but I am sure it was 24k.

What has happened, did you change something in the combined flair generation algorithm?

Comment: Note: I am now caged on the a51, and also most of my posts there is deleted (on a different reason, the a51 system deletes most old posts), my summed repu would be around 3k there. Maybe the repu on the deleted posts of the caged a51 users is somehow calculated as existing rep in the view of the combined flair?

Comment: What's "caged" mean?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: Suspended, I assume, given that that's peterh's current account status on A51.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It is the prison term of our current micro-universe.